# What is wrong with my algorithm on "Path Sum" from leetcode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am practicing on leetcode but stuck in one test, not able to figure out my mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Question:
Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return true if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals targetSum.

A leaf is a node with no children.

example 1:[image]

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
from collections import deque 
#code starts from here
class Solution:
    def hasPathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> bool:
        stack = collections.deque()
        sum1 = 0
        while(1):
            while(root != None):
                stack.append(root)
                sum1 = sum1 + root.val
                
                root = root.left
            if(sum1 == targetSum):
                return("true")
            
            if(root):
                root = stack.pop()
                sum1 = sum1 - root.val
                root = root.right
            else:
               
                break
            
        return("false")
```

My code is falling on this test case:

```
[1,2,3]
5
```

[image: Failed test case scenario]

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also retake the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through your code manually. I'll use hyphens to denote the state of each variable at a given point during execution.

```
  First iteration of outer while loop:
  - stack (top -> bottom = left -> right) = empty
  - sum1 = 0
  - root = node 1
    First iteration of inner while loop:
      stack.append(node 1)
      sum1 = 0 + 1 = 1
      root = node 1.left = node 2
    Second iteration of inner while loop:
      stack.append(node 2)
      sum1 = 1 + 2 = 3
      root = node 2.left = None (break)
  - stack = node 2, node 1
  - sum1 = 3
  - root = None
    sum1 == 5 is false, so do not return "true"
    root = None, break
  Outside while loop
    return "false"
```

Well, your code returned the string "false" but a boolean value false was expected. A more alarming bug that you need to fix is that **only the left path** will be checked. You need to change the logic for the inner while loop.

For example, you'll notice that for the below test case:

```
[1, 2, 3]
4
```

Your code will return false (assuming you fix the return type error), even though the right path sums to 4. This is due to the fact that only the left path (1, 2) is traversed.